# Internal server error after changin php.ini

Tags: php, cpanel

So i was having issues while sending emails from my php code, the emails doulnd't get out from my domain, but they worked with in the domain, example, from `info@domain.com` to `another_mail@domain.com` it was ok, but from `info@domain.com` to `my_personal_mail@gmail.com` it wasn't. So i tried to add the following line to my `php.ini`:

```
sendmail_path="/mail"
```

And the following started to appear in my index (and all other pages):

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@domain.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

After that I erased that line, but there was no turning back.
Also I tried to use the cpanel `MultiPHP INI editor` to override the `php.ini` file, but the problem still persist
Also i tried to add this line to my `php.ini`:

```
sendmail_path = "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i"
```

I wasn't able to find the server error log.

Comment: Are you sure you are changing the same `php.ini` file every time. If you removed the line its action should be removed. I assume you restarted the web server each time you change the `php.ini`

Comment: I changed every `php.ini` file to have the default value. I can't restart the webserver because isn't in my hosting plan

Comment: If the email works for within the domain, then its probably not the path.  It sounds like you are working with multiple php.ini files.  If its a shared server then you will not have access to the php.ini.  How did you change it in the first place ?  Did you try to change it in a number of ways ?

Comment: @RohitGupta, i'm working with multiple `php.ini` files, but I used a tool of cpanel to restore it and it didn't work.

Comment: I didnt have much success with using the php.ini from within cpanel either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was given by the support of my service, they "reloaded the php version" and "restoring" the permissions on the system files.

Comment: Thanks for following up Andres! Always nice to see a success story.